# add one more property in poll based on django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I come from ASP.NET MVC background. When I follow the django tutorial(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/), I found it is hard to change the model or add new template.

For this tutorial, if I want to choose what color the Choice will appear as to the users who vote on them when I create a Choice for a Question. ***What are the steps to do that***? I just found django tutorial is not organized like Microsoft's tutorial, so it is hard to work on the python project.

Comment: May be you are first person who told Django documentation is not organised. May be you are used with Microsoft pattern. Try to remove that pattern from your heart and feel Django deeply. The docs are more than awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in Choice Model if you want to add color field:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then Run following command to reflect above changes in database :

> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> python manage.py migrate

Comment: It should be have default value: color = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=200)

Comment: Can we specify color like this way:  Specify any valid web color in hex triplet format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet). When a voter views a Choice, its font-color should be the color that I choose. I am able to specify a different color for each Choice.